# How to get desired FireFox last tab behavior?

Tags: firefox

All tabs should be the same; so if any of the have a 'close' button, they all should, including the last tab. I see no reason that a tab's close button should suddenly vanish simply b/c that tab has become the last one open. If I have N tabs open, and park the mouse over the left-most tab's close button, this vanishing close button trick means now I have to make a large mouse move to get to the app's close button. Unsat. Mouse moves = too many milliseconds wasted.

Closing the last tab should NOT take me to my home page, or any other page whatsoever. I want the browser to close with the last tab. I do not expect or want "new tab" behavior when I click a Close button.

Now, I've gone into about:config and played with browser.tabs.closeWindoWithLastTab, but this setting oversteps its purpose; while it does make the browser close, for some inexplicable reason, it also suppresses the last tab's close button!

I have tried the "last tab close button" add-on, and while this does restore the close button, the add-on oversteps by taking the liberty of turning closeWindowWithLastTab off.

Is there some way out of this pickle? Is it too hard to just code things to provide simple, orthogonal actions, so that *everybody* can config the UI to their liking, and not just to a few pre-fab configurations that the developers *think* everyone should like?

Btw, FF 13.0.1 on ms windows

Comment: There's a fine line between a configurable, intuitive UI and [this](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-CC_86LEX3pw/Tcq3jMkJG9I/AAAAAAAABpY/FyBrN4P2Pxs/s1600/free-bulk-renaming-tool.png). It's actually very difficult to find the perfect midpoint between "configuring everything" and "configuring nothing"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the [Last Tab Close Button](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/last-tab-close-button/) add on to close the last window intead of opening `about:newtab`.

Steps:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to open the Add-ons Manager.
2. Click `Options` in the `Last tab close button` entry.
3. Choose `Close window`.

   [image: screenshot]
4. Click `OK`.

Comment: Yeah, I guess this answers the question as I stated it. The part I left out is that I want new tabs to open a specific URL, and that gets twisted up with the close behavior, too. But I forgot to mention that, so +1

Comment: I believe this no longer works, but it could be some strange interaction with my other extensions.